# Selecting data of a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `customers`, with a field called `telnumber`.

The `telnumber` contains a telephone number, but does have some invalid data.  So I want to select data from the customer table, field telnumber where the value is between 9 and 11 in length and is numeric.

Comment: What have you tried?  The SO community prefers that you demonstrate some effort before getting help.

Answer (score 4):

This should return only records that have length between 9 and 11 AND are numeric.

```
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE LENGTH(telnumber) BETWEEN 9 AND 11
AND telnumber REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement of `9 and 11 in length and is numeric` means that you automatically reject any common "phone number punctuation" such as dashes, spaces and parentheses. Your `telnumber` field may actually contain properly "punctuated" telephone numbers. I think a more complete solution would use [MySQL's RegEx](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) to test for valid phone numbers.

Here's another [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) to get you started and perhaps thinking of alternatives.

Comment: +1, this isn't what he's asking, but is probably what he should do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM customers c
WHERE LENGTH(c.telnumber) BETWEEN 9 AND 11
  AND c.telnumber REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

OR

```
SELECT
   *
FROM customers c
WHERE LENGTH(c.telnumber) >=9 AND LENGTH(c.telnumber) <= 11
   AND c.telnumber REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: what about testing that it is numeric?

Comment: Does MySQL optimize `BETWEEN` to `>= AND <=` for numeric values?

Comment: @Abe Regex is taking care of testing for numeric

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) and use LENGTH(), a simple query would look something like this:

`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (LENGTH(telnumber) > 9) AND (LENGTH(telnumber) < 11`)

This can be expanded to suit your needs.

Comment: Brilliant , thanks ...but is there a way to only get numberic from these results

Comment: Take a look at @John's answer :-) He's doing it a bit better than I am.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this stored procedure to determine if it is a numeric data type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsNumericEx( @value nvarchar(max) )
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @isInt BIT

     SELECT  @isInt = 1 
     WHERE   @value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%'
             AND LEN(REPLACE(@value, '.', '')) >= LEN(@value) - 1
             AND CHARINDEX('-', @value) IN (0, 1)
             AND CHARINDEX('-', @value, 2) = 0

     RETURN ISNULL(@isInt, 0)
END
GO
```

And the query:

```
select * from myTable where isNumericEx(mycolumn) = 1 and length(mycolumn) between 9 and 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in mySql, but I think you can simply use:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE CONVERT(telnumber, INTEGER) IS NOT NULL
AND LENGTH(telnumber) >= 9
AND LENGTH(telnumber) <= 11;
```